# テーブル名の付け方について

Tags: sql

SQL初心者です。

勉強のため、自宅で家計簿アプリを開発しようと思っているんですが、テーブル名に迷っています。

具体的には、以下のXXXの部分に悩んでます。
候補としては「monthly_expense」が挙がっていますが
なんだかしっくりこないのでアドバイスお願いします。

■テーブル名
1.XXX：年月毎の出費情報を管理するテーブル
■カラム名
ID          id
年月      year_month
カテゴリ    catg_id
カテゴリ名   catg_name
名称      name
数量      item_num
金額      price

■テーブル名
2.catg_master：出費の区分を管理するテーブル
■カラム名
カテゴリID  catg_id
カテゴリ名   catg_name

### 追記

kabichanさん

ご指摘ありがとうございます。
以下のように修正しました。
修正箇所を○、削除箇所を×にしてあります。

■テーブル名
○1.expense：年月毎の出費情報を管理するテーブル
■カラム名
ID id
○出費年月 enpense_date
カテゴリ catg_id
×カテゴリ名 catg_name
名称 name
数量 item_num
金額 price

■テーブル名
2.catg_master：出費の区分を管理するテーブル
■カラム名
カテゴリID catg_id
カテゴリ名 catg_name

Comment: もしよろしければ「承認済み」のボタンを押して頂けますとありがたいです。「この質問には承認された返答がある」という印にもなりますので。

Answer (score 2):

おそらくこの種類の質問はスタックオーバーフローではなく、ソフトウェアエンジニアリング向けの質問になるような気がしますが、日本語版ソフトウェアエンジニアリングがなさそうなので一応回答させて頂きます。

ネーミングコンベンションは個人や会社によってそれぞれ違いますので、あくまでも個人的な意見になりますが、まず`year_month`のデータ型を`datetime`にして、`ExpenseDate`　などにします。その方がデータを取り出す時にdaily, monthly, yearlyなどフレキシブルに対応できると思います。

そうした場合、テーブル名も`Expense`が良いのではないかと思います。（monthlyに限定しないという意味で）

あと、これも質問にはありませんが`Expense`テーブルに`catg_name`をいれる必要はありません。二つのテーブルを`join`することによって、`catg_name`を取り出すというのが`relational database`のメリットです。